# how to enter bash password via python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, archlinux

I apologize in advance if I'm not clear in this post but I'll try to be as clear as I can.

So I'm making a python script for installing my favourite packages in arch-linux so for eg if I ever have to do a fresh install I can just load my script and all my packages (or just one package) would be installed. I want my script to be able to install packages from different package managers.

So far I have it working with the default pacman when I use the os.system() and run it with sudo

```
os.system('echo %s; echo y) |sudo -S sudo %s -S %s) % (prefix, package_manager, package_name)
```

which could translate to

```
os.system('echo password123; echo y) |sudo -S sudo pacman -S python-setuptools)
```

But the problem arises when I use it with yaourt ( I know it's unsafe and no longer maintained but I'm just using it for testing purposes )

I can't enter the above command because I get an error message saying I can't run makepkg as root because I could greatly damage my system.

So I've tried it with

```
y | yaourt -S package_name
```

It bypasses all the confirmation messages but It get's stuck in the console at the password. I've tried looking for a command that can enter say an x amount of y's and then when it comes to the password I could enter that in with just one line of code.

I've also tried the subprocess module, with the .Popen() and .communicate() methods where I say something like

```
p = subprocess.Popen('yaourt -S sublime-text-dev', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

p.communicate(b'password123')
```

but it still gets stuck at the password phase.

I don't want to use the Pexpect module because it isn't a default package with python and you have to install pip to get it to work and I want to be able to run my script without having to manually install anything.

Here's my function just in case

```
def install_package_suggestion(package_dictionary, sudo_password): 
package_name = input('Enter name of package to install: ').lower()

if package_name not in package_dictionary:
    print(package_name + ' is not in the suggestion list')
else :
    package_manager = package_dictionary[package_name][0]
    prefix = '(echo %s;echo y;)|sudo -S sudo' % (sudo_password) if package_manager == 'pacman' else 'echo %s|' % (sudo_password)
    command = '%s %s -S %s' % (prefix, package_manager, package_name)

    res = os.system(command)
```

If anyone can help me at all I would greatly appreciate it !

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but why not just run your _script_ with `sudo`, so it doesn't need to sudo the subcommands? (Also, to provision a machine like this, you might want to look into Ansible or other orchestration tools unless you're writing this for fun.)

Comment: Thanks ! I was fixated on this problem that I didn't even realize. That should tidy up my code abit :)

Comment: A lot of password prompts will try to read from the terminal, not stdin, so you might want to look at an `expect` like wrapper such as `pexpect`

Comment: Thanks man, didn't know that. Yeah I'm thinking at the start of my script I should write code to manually install pip and then Pexpect  and then run my code with Pexpect to deal with the password situation. I don't think there's another way to do it. Only wanted to use default python packages but I suppose I shouldn't be too stubborn